# In Face Detection process, is it possible to form/generate an image of person whose faces got matched either self/ matching with some other face model

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

System requirement:

1. face_recognition version: face_recognition-1.2.3
2. Python version: 3.9
3. Operating System: Linux distro, actually docker image : python:3.9-buster

Description:

I have trained many people's face and stored their face-model with 128 nd array through pickle.dump
My detection is also working well, no issue with it.

When a person's face is recognized, I return the name of the person's even if I am getting multiple face found issues, but now I want to return the image of person's face to whomever it matches with.

I want to convert matched person's image from stored face-model.

Please guide me through the steps to make conversion of face-model to image, any dlib-lib reference, or other library would be a great help.

I am expecting to convert matched person's image from stored face-model.
I read the dlib lib functions but could not figure out the result, please guide.

Comment: You can not get face image from face recognition model. What you have to do is to find an image in your training dataset by key obtained by face recognition..

Comment: ⁠Hey [Hihikomori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10452046/hihikomori),

Actually, there's no image stored in dataset, the pre-trained face encoding file object is stored, Can you please elaborate on your approach, I didn't get "key obtained by face recognition"